# Soft real time optimization for Applications under Windows/Linux possible?

Tags: linux, windows, optimization, operating-system, latency

I'm trying to figure out how to optimize different OS and Hardware for latency.

In the past few weeks I've been tinkering with different versions of Windows and different Hardware and became pretty disappointed with what room for improvement these things have to offer in that regard.

I wanted to ask here if maybe I'm missing something or am wrong about something.

Let's say we have a system with all the standard components. All of these components send interrupt requests to the cpu when then want to complete an operation. Cpu spends cycles completing this request. All cycles have fixed length.

Basically, most of how the interrupt requests are handled is written within the drivers for your hardware and if it's badly optimized your only option is to try another version of the drivers.

The most you can do to optimize the system is disconnecting devices you don't need or enabling MSI-Mode through the registry if the hardware supports it.

Are there some advantages that you have when choosing a particular OS (w7/w8/w10/linux) that give you some benefits or more control over your system's latency.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: This question is too broad by S.O. standards. As you have discovered, there is not much flexibility in certain(many/most?) use cases when using a consumer level system. It seems like you're trying to get Ferrari performance from a 1962 VW Beetle. Do you know about RTOS class of systems, it sounds like that might be more appropriate. Else for help here, you'll need to pose your Q with reproducible code and try to solve one problem at a time. Good luck.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: If an interrupt driver that conforms to the OS requirements is not good enough, you need a different system.  Use embedded controllers instead.  They will not be able to run Office, BitTorrent, VLC, Skype, your build system etc etc concurrently, but the interrupt latency will be less, and more predictable.

Comment: All right, thanks for the replies and sorry if the question wasn't in line with the guidelines. I just spent 2 weeks dealing with this subject and this place seemed like the most appropriate one to ask such kind of question.